# Binding a C++ class member function to Java using JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to bind a native function to Java using JNI RegisterNatives. If the function is in the global scope I can easily bind the function and it works without an issue.

But when I am trying to bind a C++ class member function to Java the callback doesn't get called.

The declaration of my C++ function is like this:

```
void native_onCall(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint val)
```

The Java function looks like this.

```
public native void onCall(int a);
```

The native function I am trying to bind is in the same class as my RegisterNatives method call. Here is a snippet of how I used a typedef to define the function pointer and added it to JNINativeMethod struct.

```
typedef void (MyClass::*func_pointer)(JNIEnv*, jobject, jint);
func_pointer cbptr;

JNINativeMethod[index].name = const_cast<char*>("onCall");
JNINativeMethod[index].signature = const_cast<char*>("(I)V");
JNINativeMethod[index].fnPtr = (void*)cbptr;

env->RegisterNatives(jclass, JNINativeMethod, index);
```

I also used std::bind and a lambda function to bind the function pointer but it doesn't work.

If anyone can point out a way to bind a class member function to java using JNI or what I am doing wrong here it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently using an instance member function is not the way to go at this.
By using a static function I managed to handle the call inside a class.

Comment: True. Binding a Java native method to an non-static method of a C++ class is tricky: which instance will you use?

Comment: @AlexCohn I used a static method inside a class and used a static instance of the class inside the method to get the work done. I made the class basically a singleton and change the design of rest of the code a bit to use this single instance.